# Kotlin: How to async await a list of identical methods?

Tags: kotlin

I have a few hundred Java class instances that all need to complete their .calculate() method or die in 10 minutes.  They will grab up the CPU and memory, so I'd like to only allow 5 (threads?) at once.  I believe I'm close, but coming from a Java background I'm not yet familiar enough with kotlin coroutines (vs java ExecutorServices) to make this compile.

```
// ...my logic to create a stream of identical class type instances 
// that all have a vanilla blocking .calculate():Double method...
// which I now want to (maybe?) map to Jobs

listOf(MyClass(1), MyClass(2), MyClass(1000))
.map {
  launch(CommonPool) {
    val errorRate: Double? = it?.calculate()
    println("${it?.javaClass?.simpleName}  $errorRate") // desired output
    errorRate
  }
}
.collect(Collectors.toList<Job>())

jobs.forEach {
    println(it.join())
}
```

And then I think I need to wrap the calculate with a non-blocking calculate?  Or a blocking, but timeout limited? Should that "runBlocking" be there?  Better as a lambda in the above code?

```
fun MyClass.calculateTimeLimited(): Double = runBlocking {
  withTimeout(TIMEOUT) {
    this.calculate() // <-- doesn't compile! "this" is "CoroutineScope"
```

Comment: What is `.map{}` called on?

Comment: A stream of MyClass objects

Comment: Does it has to be a JDK8 stream? Not `Sequence` or `Iterable`?

Comment: This will not work with `.collect(`. You can remove it

Comment: If you want to limit execution to X threads, you should probably create your own Executor which uses X threads, then convert it to a CoroutineDispatcher using `Executor.asCoroutineDispatcher()` and use that instead of CommonPool. CommonPool is like a default Executor with good default values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you are aware but there is this great document: [coroutines by example](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#cancellation-and-timeouts).  I linked the specific section on cancellations and timeouts.  Below is my implementation of your problem:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CommonPool
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.newSingleThreadContext
import java.util.*
import kotlin.system.measureNanoTime

internal val random = Random()

fun createRandArray(n: Long): Array<Int> {
    return createRandTArray(n).toTypedArray()
}

fun createRandTArray(n: Long): IntArray {
    return random.ints(n, 0, n.toInt()).toArray()
}

var size: Long = 1_000_000
var nRepeats: Int = 11
var nDrops: Int = 1

fun <T> benchmark(name: String,
                  buildSortable: (Long) -> T,
                  sort: (T) -> Any) {
    val arrays = List(nRepeats) { buildSortable(size) }
    val timesMS = arrays.map { measureNanoTime { sort(it) } / 1_000_000 }.drop(nDrops) // for JVM optimization warmup
    // println(timesMS)
    println("[$name] Average sort time for array of size $size: ${timesMS.average() } ms")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    size = 1_000_000
    nRepeats = 6

    benchmark("Array<Int>",
            buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size).toTypedArray() },
            sort = ::mergeSort)

    benchmark("ListLike Array<Int>",
            buildSortable = { size -> SortingArray(createRandTArray(size).toTypedArray()) },
            sort = { array -> mergeSortLL(array) })  // oddly ::mergeSortLL is refused

    benchmark("ListLike IntArray",
            buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size).asComparableList() },
            sort = { array -> mergeSortLL(array) })  // oddly ::mergeSortLL is refused

    benchmark("IntArray",
            buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size) },
            sort = ::mergeSortIA)

    benchmark("IntArray multi-thread (CommonPool) with many array copies",
            buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size) },
            sort = { mergeSortCorou(it) })

    val origContext = corouContext
    corouContext = newSingleThreadContext("single thread")
    benchmark("IntArray multi-thread (one thread!) with many array copies",
            buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size) },
            sort = { mergeSortCorou(it) })
    corouContext = origContext

    benchmark("Java int[]",
            buildSortable = { size -> createRandTArray(size) },
            sort = { MergeSorter.sort(it) })
}
```

I got the output:

```
 Hit the timeout (CancellationException).
 Out of 100 computations, 45 completed.
```

You can play with the `timeOut` value (currently 500 ms).  Each job has a different random execution time from 0 to 1000 ms, so around half get executed before the time out.

However you might have a harder time to implement this for your specific problem.  Your computations will have to be *cancellable*.  Read the section on cancellation carefully in the document I linked above.  Basically your computation either has to call one of the `suspend` functions in `kotlinx.coroutines` (this is what I did since I call `delay`), or use `yield` or `isActive`.

---

**EDIT**: related to comment on cancelling any job (non-cancellable/non-suspendable):

No, there is no magic here.  Making a computation truly cancellable is very difficult, no matter what framework you use.  Notoriously Java has `Thread.stop()`, which seems to do what you would want, but was [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

I tried to use coroutines to solve the simpler problem of stopping submitting new jobs after the timeout, but where jobs which started before the timeout can run far beyond the timeout without being cancelled/interrupted.  I spent some time on it and could not find an easy solution with coroutines.  It could be done using the standard Java concurrency constructs.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work if the code I'm calling isn't cancellable?  a "withTimeoutNoSeriouslyItBetterEndWhenIWantItTo" function...

Comment: No.  I added an EDIT in my answer with more text.

Comment: Trying to answer your comment, I realized there were bugs in my code, so I fixed them.  Bug 1: `completedComputations` should be a thread-safe set.  Bug 2: I forgot to wait at the end of my program (`Thread.sleep()`) in case other threads were not yet done.  Bug 3: because of Bug 2, the code I had was actually not cancelling the jobs although it looked like it did.  It seems there must not be one global `withTimeout`, but one for each job.  This seems odd since according to the doc the children of a job are cancelled too.  I'm not sure if it's a coroutine bug.

Answer (score 5):

My take (sorry can't test it o my machine):

```
val results = streamOfInstances.asSeqence().map {
    async(CommonPool) {
        val errorRate: Double? = it?.calculate()
        println("${it?.javaClass?.simpleName}  $errorRate")
        errorRate
    }
}

runBlocking {
    results.forEach {
        println(it.await())
    }
}
```

Key difference from your code:

- I use `async` instead of `launch` since I am collecting the result
- The blocking operation (`join()` or `await()`) is inside `runBlocking{}`
- I use Kotlin's `map`, not the JDK8 API

Comment: Job.await doesn't seem to exist for me.  Dang, it was because I was casting to Job, and needed to be Deferred<Double?>

Comment: There should't be a need to cast anything in this code. Yes it is `Deferred<>` :D